# Why typescript doesn't override the property which defined in global typing?

Tags: typescript

I want to override the property `name` in `Database` interface in global typing.

I have module `@app/db` which points to `./db.ts` in the applicaiton (using `tsconfig` alias):

```
// db.ts:
export interface Database {
  name: string;
  other: string;
}

export const create = (database: Partial<Database>) => {};
```

In `index.ts` I using this `@app/db` module:

```
import { create } from '@app/db';

create({ name: 'bar_db' });
```

In the "global typing" I try to "override" the `name` property like so:

```
import '@app/db';

declare module '@app/db' {
  interface Database {
    name: 'bla_db' | 'bar_db'; // <-- allow only those values.
    global: string;
  }
}
```

I'm sure the typing is working well and typescript is know about this `d.ts` file. I check that.

But when I using the typing it should throw. the `Database.name` property is `string` and should be literal string from the global `d.ts`.

```
import { create } from '@app/db';

create({ name: 'blabla', global: '..' }); //<-- name is from ./db, but global from global typing.
// should throw because 'blabla' is not allow.
```

Why typescript is not override this property?

[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zarlax?file=index.ts,tsconfig.json,types%2Fnode%2Findex.d.ts,db.ts)

Comment: You are using a static import. This makes the declaration a file and not an ambient declaration. (Hint: remove the static import)

Comment: What do you mean about "static import"? the `@app/db` is simulate a lib from node_modules. think about it i can't change the `@app/db`. I import it in the app: `index.ts` and use it. also I want to "override" the typing.

Comment: `import "@app/db"` is a static import.

Comment: Got what you mean. but if I remove `import "@app/db"` then others exports from `@app/db` will not exist. because it's rewrite the module typing. I want to extend it. 
Also, I update my question and stackblitz to show you the global property is coming from the global typing. but name is coming from the local interface –